# Java - Using DocumentBuilder/XML parser in Android studio

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, dom

I'm trying to use dom XML parser but it crashes at with IOException

```
Document doc = builder.parse(file);
```

The code:

```
try {

   DocumentBuilderFactory factory =  DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
   DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
   File file = new File(getResources().getResourceName(R.raw.fooddata));
   Document doc = builder.parse(file);

}catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SAXException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I think theres something wrong the the file path.
The fooddata.xml file is in /res/xml/fooddata.xml & /res/raw/fooddata.xml, I've tried access it in different way but nothing works.

I get IOException from try/catch

How do I get the builder.parse(file) to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The fooddata.xml file is in /res/xml/fooddata.xml & /res/raw/fooddata.xml

Those are files *on your development machine*. They are *not* files on the Android device. Resources are merely entries in the APK file on the device.

Replace:

```
File file = new File(getResources().getResourceName(R.raw.fooddata));
Document doc = builder.parse(file);
```

with:

```
Document doc=builder.parse(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.fooddata));
```

Comment: It seems to work better but now I get a OutOfMemoryError. The xml file is 30mb.

Comment: @SimonAndersson That is the problem with DOM: It's memory-intensive. You may have to use SAX or StAX instead.

Comment: @Andreas so the issue is ram on android device? Because my emulator works fine

Comment: @SimonAndersson That is my guess, yes.

Comment: @SimonAndersson: If you are planning on reading all of the data in that XML file into memory at once (DOM), you are doomed. You may not have 30MB of heap space for your app. If you only need a subset of that XML, get rid of the extra stuff from the resource, as there is no point in packaging that extra data and wasting space on the user's device.

Comment: @CommonsWare I need pretty much all data. Do you think it will work with SAX or StAX that Andreas suggested?

Comment: @SimonAndersson: No, because 30MB is 30MB, no matter how you parse it, and you may not have that much heap space. Redesign your app to not need all of it in memory at once, and consider a different data store that better supports that sort of approach. For example, you could ship a SQLite database file with your app instead of an XML file, and then [use `SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) to access the data. Now, you can do small queries to get the bits of data that you need, rather than needing to hold the entire dataset in RAM at once.

Comment: Nvm, I dont need 30mb at once, so I need to change how I do this. Thanks for the help! I'm new at android/java so this will be a challenge